# How can i remove unnecessary top padding in cardview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I managed to implement Cardviews in my app, but the cardview show an unnecessary padding in the top.

[image]

What i want to achieve is to get a header image like this :

[image]

Here's my cardview Layout file :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/programCardview"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/programHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:src="@drawable/createdprogramviewcard"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/programTitle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Programme d'endurance"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/objectif"
            android:layout_below="@+id/programTitle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Objectif : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/programObjectif"
            android:layout_below="@+id/programTitle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="6 séances"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/objectif"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/programWorkouts"
            android:layout_below="@+id/programTitle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="6 séances" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code of the RecyclerView :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPrograms"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I manage to change the attribute cardUseCompatPadding but that not affect the internal form of the cardview, it's just there to separate them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the xml for your AdapterView(RecliclerView/ListView)

Comment: try changing this atribute card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: I edited the question with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem by changing the height of the imageView to 130dp. Apparently since i made the with of the image to match_parent, i had to find the exact height that will suit the image inside the cardview without giving it some extra padding.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is due to two reasons, the first is that the height property of the **CardView** is in **match_parent** or in a larger size than the components occupy and at the same time the **gravity** property of the layout is in **center**.

To fix it just set the gravity of the LinearLayout to center | fill or just to fill.

Answer (score 0):

I used these below attributes and it works for me.

```
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
```

Or you can just use MaterialCardView instead of legacy CardView